# Can I disable automatic production hurrying?

Tags: civilization-4

In Civilization 4 when I enable production automation sometimes production is hurried automatically, either by sacrificing population or by spending money.

Is there a way to disable this and still use the city governor?

In C2C many buildings require a minimum city size and the automatic hurrying seriously impedes the city growth. Also I want to avoid the increased inflation later in the game (when money is used to hurry production)

Comment: Short comment before I dig up a screenshot, but the city automation options on the bottom (to the right of the production selection area) should have a prevent rush toggle.

Comment: Seems I'm mistaken about that. Doesn't look like there's a way.